Issue with Initial Rendering with Formik, MaterialUI ( React, Typescript)
In the initial rendering of a dynamic header column in my Formik form, the first column - "indicator" column is picking up different styling compared to other columns. Specifically, the values for its styling are empty. All other columns are rendered correctly with the appropriate styles.
Interestingly, when I navigate to the next page and then return to this page, the styling issue for the "indicator" column is automatically fixed. This suggests that the problem might be related to the initial render cycle.
I'm using Formik for form management and Material-UI for styling. Could someone please help me identify and resolve this issue?
